# My Controller is not working in laravel project I am facing this error "Class App\Http\Controllers\HelloController does not exist"

Tags: laravel, view, controller, routes

My controller is not working when i am attaching router and controller with each other. It is showing the error

> Class App\Http\Controllers\HelloController does not exist.

I hope my syntax and everything is right but can't figure out the issue.

Filename is also same as class name.

namespace I used is :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\;
```

Route code:

```
Route::get('sayHello', 'HelloController@index');
```

Controller Code:

```php
class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check for spelling mistake.

Comment: Hi, You can checked by running command ```compuser dump-autoload```

Comment: @DhavalGohel please tell me what can i check with this command ?

Comment: @HaseebAttique Are you run this command in terminal?  i think it cache issue in laravel.

Comment: Yes i run in terminal.

Comment: Cache cleared but issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace for the controller should be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Notice it doesn't have "\" at the end.

Once you have changed the above it will be worth running:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

---

When creating a controller in the future it will probably be worth using the artisan command `make:controller`:

```
php artisan make:controller SomeNewController
```

---

The issue is the `<? php` at the top of your controller class. It should be `<?php` (no space)

Comment: I did the same, corrected the namespace and also checked by creating new controller using artisan command but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you changed any of the out-of-the-box configuration i.e. changed the default namespace?

Comment: No i did'nt change any default namespace.

Comment: @HaseebAttique It sounds like it's potentially a cache issue. Please can you try running `php artisan route:list`. If you see the `HelloController@index` route then the framework should be running correctly. I would then suggest trying to visit the url in a different browser to see if you're still getting a 404.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vL5LVr7

Please have a look at the attached screenshot. It is the result of php artisan route:list.

Comment: @HaseebAttique Do you already have this is github or anything? If not, can you add it to github?

Comment: https://github.com/Haseebch134/Laravel-Project-

Please have a look sir.

Comment: @HaseebAttique Did this solve your issue? If so please may you mark the question as accepted :)

Comment: @HaseebAttique I did. I updated my answer yesterday (the last line) :)

Comment: Thankyou so much @Ross for your help. Really matters a lot to me as i am beginner. Really appreciate it !

Thanks

Comment: Sure Sir let me do it !

Comment: @HaseebAttique I'm glad I could help! If this has answered your question please may you mark it as accepted. Thanks.